# Is there a way to receive images in rasa?

Tags: twilio, rasa

In my rasa bot I would like users to be able to send in an image, and then trigger a custom action that can fetch some of the twilio message parameters (such as the url of where it is stored)

At the moment I am trying to do this in a slot and a slot validation action but (unsurprisingly!) I am getting the error `'NoneType' object has no attribute 'replace'`

Does anyone have any tips on how to do such an action?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you solved the problem?

Comment: You can use custom connector for that.

Comment: Have you found any solution for that @ShaidaMuhammad

Answer (score 0):

It appears that [in the Rasa Twilio connector only the text of a message and the sender are extracted from the incoming webhook](https://github.com/RasaHQ/rasa/blob/7625fcaec9a5d1f47dbcc093a405e9369e7261fc/rasa/core/channels/twilio.py#L128-L147).

In order to get other data from the message, you would have to implement the [`get_metadata` method](https://github.com/RasaHQ/rasa/blob/7625fcaec9a5d1f47dbcc093a405e9369e7261fc/rasa/core/channels/twilio.py#L135) and have it return other data that the message includes, including media URLs.

I've not used Rasa myself, so I don't know if this is something you can implement or if it is a feature request to Rasa.

Comment: this sounds like a cool idea ill give it a go! thanks